# How to validate an XML against schema using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, unmarshalling

I am working with `XML` and `JAXB` as I am unmarshalling and marshalling the XML into Java objects and vice versa. Now I am trying to validate our XML against our schema(test.xsd). Suppose if any required field is missing in my XML, then I would like to know which field is missing after validating the XML against schema test.xsd.

```
public void unmarshal(final InputStream is) {
    final XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    final XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(is);

    Object req = unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);

    // how would I validate here?
}
```

How would I validate my XML against test.xsd schema. My test.xsd schema path is -

> C:\workspace\one\two\three\src\main\java\com\package\serv\ap\versionOne\test.xsd

**UPDATE: loading test.xsd as:**

```
Schema schema = factorySchema.newSchema(new File("C:\\workspace\\one\\two\\three\\src\\main\\java\\com\\package\\serv\\ap\\versionOne\\test.xsd"));
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You just need to set an instance of [`javax.xml.validation.Schema`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/Schema.html) on the `Unmarshaller` before you do the unmarshal.  You can specify an implementation of `ValidationEventHandler` on the `Unmarshaller` to catch any problems that occur during the unmarshal process.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#setSchema%28javax.xml.validation.Schema%29

**For More Information**

I have written more about this use case on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html

Comment: Thank you Blaise, that was indeed a useful information. I have one quick question, while loading the test.xsd the path I am giving is absolute right now, I am not sure how do I set the relative path in order to have it loaded. Anything on this would be great.Updated my question regardign the same

Comment: @akiiddweeber - You should be able to use a relative path.  You just need to ensure the path is relative to what your Java VM considers the working directory.

Comment: Thanks and yes that's correct, so as updated in my question, if that is my absolute path, how should I find out the relative path in intelliJ :( Generally it do pick from resource but I am clueless why is it not picking it up from there (as relative) :(

Comment: @akiiddweeber - You could pick it up as a resource (from the classpath) as well using a `ClassLoader`.  Generally when I need to pick something up from a relative path and I don't know the working directory I specify my best guess, and then based on the error which usually contains a full path I figure out what my relative path should be.  IDE's also usually provide a config setting to specify what you want the working directory to be.

Comment: Thank you @ Blaise it kind of worked, I just did the following:     `Schema schema = factorySchema.newSchema(this.getClass().getResource("//test.xsd"));` and changed the `single-slash operator` to `double`- Strange but sort of worked, still testing but looks like its fixed :)