# How to validate XML without a schema

Tags: java, xml, xsd, schema, xsd-validation

Is that a way to validate XML without schemas?

I am researching the concept to validate XML without using XML Schema, rather to use raw Java to construct the validation. I know about using SAX or DOM parsers to parse the XML file, but I have no idea whether either of these parsers are used validate XML in a manner similar to XML Schema.

If anyone has an idea how to validate XML without using schemas using any tool (Java or any other), kindly share your ideas.

Comment: What validation do you want to perform?  Most XML libraries will change you have valid XML for you so all you need to do is read the XML successfully.

Comment: You can find answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24760796/how-to-validate-an-xml-against-schema-using-jaxb

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Currently i am having the xml, which is need to validate whether to check the given xml is exactly suits to the request. I am using the schemas(XSD) to perform the validation for given xml. But my query is, is that a change to validate the xml using java or any other tool which is similar to xml schemas(XSD).

Comment: It's completely unclear what you are asking. Validation without a schema is a logical impossibility (if schema is understood as any restriction regarding the structure or content of an XML document). XML Schema is not the only validation language, are you asking about other validation languages? Are you concerned with well-formedness?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can write a program to do custom validation of XML. The question is, why would you want to? Declarative schema languages were invented for a good reason.

If you really do need to enforce validation rules that are difficult to express in a declarative schema language, consider using an XSLT stylesheet: it will be a fraction of the number of lines of code you would write in Java, and much easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yes, you are right. but my concern is, i am using the paid version of software to create the xsd, i don't think that there is a opensource tool for to creation xsd's. since that i would like to find or to do research for alternate opensource tool to validate the xml rather to pay huge for specific software's. +1 in-case if you suggest me a opensource tool or any other solution for xml validation.

Comment: @HariRam What are you talking about? The only tool required for the creation of XSD schema documents is a text editor; the last I looked, there were open-source version of both vi and emacs.  It's true that an XSD-aware editor helps a good deal, but the best one of those I know hardly has a huge cost.

Comment: @HariRam: Many people use, even prefer, text editors for creating XSDs.  (I use emacs.)  Many free choices are available.  For validation, Xerces-J (open source) does an excellent job of validating against an XSD; the sample directory contains many examples of how to use it.      If your real point wasn't that you wanted to validate without a schema but that you wanted to validate using free/open-source tools, then you really have to improve your question asking skills.

Comment: @kjhughes My point is simple, i am doing research to find the alternate for the paid software, either it could be a opensource tool or any alternate to the schema validation. in this question my view is to use the different set of validation process to determine the xml. Currently i am paying huge amount to the schema creation and validating the xml, if i get anything freeware for schema creation or any other alternate way to do so, it will be more helpful me.

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen You are right, the best tool for xsd-aware is huge cost. i am trying to get alternate to those process.

Comment: You are fortunate indeed that you have the luxury to write Java code without incurring any costs. For most people, buying off-the-shelf software for a hundred dollars or so is far cheaper than a day of a programmer's time.

Comment: @HariRam: Had your original question stated "*i am doing research to find the alternate for the paid software*" as you say now rather than "*Is that a way to validate the xml without schemas*" as your question asked, (1) you would have saved us all time and (2) you would have immediately been told that [**questions asking for tool and library recommendations are against protocol here**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).   Sigh.  Only redeeming value is that later readers might benefit from the answers we've provided to the question that you seemed to have been asking.

Comment: @kjhughes I never changed my question, based on the comment, i letting them to know what i exactly doing. i am doing research to get an alternate way to do validating the xml. As of now i am creating the schemas in huge cost software to validate the xml, since that i am trying to find the alternate way. meanwhile if i got some idea about how the xml are validated using java, i have a chance to create a tool for my own to validate the those.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks! i never going to write java program manually for the xml what i am creating for every time. If it has a possible to create a own tool to validate the xml using java, i can able to create it from my own and that will be more helpful for me. kindly suggest me the possible way to do the validation using java or any other tool which is more relevant to the opensource.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could validate XML without a schema, but it would be rather unorthodox to do so.

Schemas generically are grammars that declaratively express the acceptability of a language.  You could instead write procedural code that checked your XML against whatever criteria you wish.  Such code would be harder to use to communicate your criteria, but it is possible.  You could even use standard XML parsers to do the heavy parsing lifting (including checking for well-formedness), and simply tack-on any domain checks you require via procedural code.

If you're willing to use *some* schema but just not W3C XML Schema (XSD), you might consider DTDs, RELAX NG, or Schematron.

Answer (score 1):

In general, 'schema' is a word we use to describe a concise statement, usually in machine-processable form, of the rules we would like a collection of data (here, an XML document) to follow; 'validation' is the process of deciding whether a given collection of data does or does not follow those rules.

Validating a document without a schema would be a lot like checking to see whether a car is obeying the speed limit, on a stretch of road for which no maximum speed is prescribed, or serving as a referee in a sport with no rules at all, and thus no need for a referee:  not so much impossible as meaningless.

I suppose that in reality by "without a schema" you may mean "with a schema in some language other than XSD" -- sure, you can use DTDs or Relax NG or Schematron -- actually you could use any of a large number of other schema languages, but most of them are now defunct.  Or you may mean "without writing down validation rules in any declarative language", e.g. by writing a Java program.  Also possible, though less likely to produce reliable results.  And as Michael Kay has already suggested, a language like XSLT would allow a somewhat more compact program for most XML vocabularies.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing. Without a schema, the most you can do is check for well-formedness of the document. All other semantics are inside the schema, or must be custom coded.