# How to validate the incoming invalid XML @RequestBody with the Java Bean class

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc, jax-rs, xsd-1.1

I have a xml java bean class `Data` annotated with all the required xml annotations. Now when i try to post a xml request using postman with the correct xml format it works fine in the controller post method. But when i purposely add an extra xml tag (for testing invalid format) say `<blabla></blabla>` in postman and post it then again the controller does not throws any error and the code is working fine. Also the validator.validate() method also does not throws any error. I want to validate the invalid xml format against the Java Bean class.

Controller method:
`public DataRes ekycRequest(@RequestBody Data data)`

Note - Marshalling and Unmarshalling is the later process in the controller method.

**Scenario 1:**
There is a DTO xml bean class (Data.java) annotated with all xml annotations and has 3 fields name, age, location. Now when i try to post a xml with the correct format i.e with three xml tags it is mapped in the controller `(@RequestBody Data data)` and no error.

**Scenario 2:**
But when i try to add an additional tag purposely to test invalid xml format say  and post the xml request the `(@RequestBody Data data)` does not throws any error. I need a solution for this. It must throw error.

**Scenario 3:**
When i try to avoid one tag and post xml with 2 tags i.e. invalid format then `(@ResponseBody Data data)` throws error which is what is needed in the above case i.e. scenario 2 also.

Like in Hibernate DTO bean class (annotated with @Entity) we use @Valid annotation in controller argument to validate the incoming data.
In the similar manner is there similar approach wfor the xml annotated beans class.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting your schema for validation when unmarshalling your Java bean? It depends on what type of validation you are using? You can also find your answer [How to validate an XML against schema using JAXB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24760796/how-to-validate-an-xml-against-schema-using-jaxb) here and follow the blogpost.

Comment: Hi Sir,
I have gone though the blog but i would like to add that marshalling and unmarshalling is later process in the controller. I have made some more edits to the question so request you to help me out.