# XML validation using external XSD in java

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-validation

I wanted to validate xml file based on schema. I also wanted to give different error messages for length validation, missing child element , datatype validation etc.
I tried to use javax.xml.validation with custom error handler. Is there any other library or way to validate xml using external xsd in java?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: JAXB does a good job for that.

Comment: For some reasons , I don't want to use pojos

Comment: Please explain why your experiment with java..xml.validation failed.

Comment: It is difficult to fetch element name from the errorMessage that we get. I tried to use xmlStreamReader to get element name . But using this, I'm not able to fetch name of child name if validation is failed for it.

Comment: There is another option for XML validation, namely Saxon, but it's unclear from your question whether changing libraries is going to solve your problem. That's basically because you haven't said exactly what you are doing or how it failed.

Comment: Okay . I will take a look on it. I just wanted to validate given xml using external xsd . If xml validation failed , I need to provide list of errors with proper and custom errorMessage , element name. I might require other functionalities like making elements optional, add length and pattern validations in schema , assign set of possible values to element.

Comment: [You don't need to use pojos when using JAXB for that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24760796/3111149)

Comment: Okay. I'm trying to implement the same but I'm not getting how to create jaxb instance without knowing particular class ?