# How to validate xml using external xsd with Saxon-HE java

Tags: java, xml, xsd, saxon, xml-validation

I'm using Saxon-HE (11.3) for validating xml using external xsd. But I'm getting nullpointerexception as schemaManager is null.

`Processor processor = new Processor (false); SchemaManager manager = processor.getSchemaManager(); manager.load(new StreamSource("xsdFile));`

Getting NPE on 3rd line. I'm not getting why schemaManager is always null ?
I tried to set new Processor(true) but it didn't work.

Comment: XSD validation is only supported in Saxon EE. With Java, Apache Xerces is also an option.

Comment: Can you please share link of any article or example to implement validator using apache xerces ?

Comment: Start with https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-xs.html and https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/samples-jaxp.html#SourceValidator

Comment: Thanks ! They are importing validator, schemaFactory,etc from javax.xml , then how it is different from javax.xml ? Before saxon , I tried to use javax.xml itself.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the built-in XSD validation support in the JRE is based on an internalized version of Xerces. As for the API being the same, well, yes, that is the intent in the Java word, no? That the official API can be implemented under the hood by different parsers or parser versions. The only mayor difference between latest Apache Xerces and the built-in one is, as far as I know, that there are Xerces builds supporting XSD 1.1 while the built-in one is restricted to 1.0.

Comment: Thanks again!  My only question is that I wanted to provide custom error messages for validation failures as mentioned in below question. So I'm trying to check other options https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73150355/xml-validation-using-external-xsd-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Saxon documentation explains that

1. `new Processor(false)` creates a non-schema-aware configuration
2. `new Processor(true)` enables features such as schema processing
   that require a license key
3. with a non-schema-aware configuration,
   `processor.getSchemaManager()` returns null.

Possibly not the most elegant bit of API design, but the product is doing what the documentation says.