# Demonstrate that JAXB unmarshalling will not load an XSD schema

Tags: java, security, xsd, jaxb, unmarshalling

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24760796/how-to-validate-an-xml-against-schema-using-jaxb), given the following schema called `customer.xsd`:

```xml
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:simpleType name="stringMaxSize5">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="5"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="customer">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="stringMaxSize5"/>
                <xs:element ref="phone-number" maxOccurs="2"/>
             </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="phone-number">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The following XML document called `input.xml`:

```xml
<customer
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./customer.xsd">
    <name>Jane Doe</name>
    <phone-number/>
    <phone-number/>
    <phone-number/>
</customer>
```

And the following unmarshalling code:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

public class Unmarshal {

    @XmlRootElement(name = "customer")
    public static class Customer {
        public String name;
        @XmlElement(name="phone-number")
        public List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<PhoneNumber>();
    }

    public static class PhoneNumber {}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setSchema(null);
        Customer customer = (Customer) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("input.xml"));
        System.out.println(customer.name);
    }

}
```

The Java code is able to deserialize the XML input document into an instance of `Customer` even when this XML document produces 2 validation errors (indicated by an external editor):

```
cvc-maxLength-valid: Value 'Jane Doe' with length = '8' is not facet-valid with respect to maxLength '5' for type 'stringMaxSize5'.xml(cvc-maxLength-valid)
cvc-type.3.1.3: The value 'Jane Doe' of element 'name' is not valid.xml(cvc-type.3.1.3)
```

and

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.f: 'phone-number' can occur a maximum of '2' times in the current sequence. This limit was exceeded. No child element is expected at this point.xml(cvc-complex-type.2.4.f)
```

This means that JAXB did not validate the given XML input during unmarshalling, however:

Given that `unmarshaller.setSchema(null);` was set to DISABLE schema validation, is there a way to demonstrate that the content of the `customer.xsd` file WAS NOT accessed by the JVM when unmarshalling occurred?

In other words, is there a way to not blindly trust that the JVM won't load XSD references, even when schema validation is explicitly set to `null`?

### Update 1:

The purpose is to find out how likely are XSD schema references inside an XML document likely to become a security attack vector, as described by:

- https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Processing
- https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XML_External_Entity_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't truly understand the need to check this but here's a simple use-case that should give the proof that the XSD file won't be loaded by the JVM when unmarshalling XML :

- Create the Java Classes from XSD by any plugin you want, or like here, create it manually. Package it in jar file without the XSD in it (only Java classes)
- Write the unmarshalling code from XML in another Java program, that depends on the first JAR and run it with no XSD whatsoever in your classpath ==> Your code will still work without knowing the XSD Schema

You can also look at the Java Code itself :

- `com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl` which implements the `Unmarshaller` interface has default `schema` property to `null` (so setting it to `null` is a no-op in your above code)
- Your code doesn't reference XSD itself from which you created the Java XML-annotated-POJO : the JVM cannot guess that you write your code based on external schema.
- You could also run your program in debug mode and see that the XSD won't be loaded (again there's no reference in your Java Code : you could even have deleted it, it wouldn't have made a difference).

Still, I Hope that I've answered to your question.

Comment: Great! I've added more information to the question. I'm basically trying to find out if JAXB, in its default configuration, is open to XML External Entity attacks. Thanks!

Comment: From what I know, there's no default validation of XML Input according to XSD since the schema is null in default configuration and there's no magic autoconfig behind-the-scene. After, the Java parser can fail or be lax about XML input : it can fail on unknown field received or unknown enum values, or just ignore them / assign null. From what I read about XML External Entity attacks, you can prevent them by removing DTD support and add the schema as validator.